# How to change the orientation of the model itself?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I downloaded a bullet model from TurboSquid.

But the bullet is pointing to the left (negtive X axis).

So the whole thing needed to be turned 90 degree on Y axis to face "forward" (Z axis).

I'm making a first-person shooting game so I needed the bullet to face exactly where the camera was facing.

So if I simply set

```
bullet.gameObject.transform.rotation = Camera.main.transform.rotation;
```

The bullet will just facing "left"!

I tried to do a additional rotation after the rotation assignment as follow:

```
bullet.gameObject.transform.Rotate(Camera.main.transform.up,90);
```

It worked fine if the view is parallel to the horizon.

But it will started to facing some weird ways if you're shooting up or down!

I also tried to create an empty parent GameObject and throw the bullet in as its child, and set the parent's rotation.

Now it "always" facing "forward" (Z axis)! No matter where I turned my camera!

Could somebody please be so kind and teach me how to fix this!?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your model in a parent object, like this:

[image: Like this]

Then you can rotate the `BulletModel` 90 degrees and attach the script that moves the object to the `ParentBullet`. This should do the trick.

It's usually considered good practice overall to separate your model and logic/actual object like this.

Comment: I tried! I don't know why it'll end up "always facing forward"!?

Comment: In the `bullet.gameObject.transform.rotation` make sure the `bullet` refers to the `ParentBullet`. If it still seems to be facing in a bad direction, adjust the rotation of the `BulletModel` object.

Comment: I make the ParentBullet a prefab, and instantiate it in code, so it should be referring the ParentBullet. But it's facing forward "no matter what"!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by some weird ways!

I just set its forward to the camera's right, and its right to the camera's back.

```
bullet.gameObject.transform.forward = Camera.main.transform.right;
bullet.gameObject.transform.right = -Camera.main.transform.forward;
```

But I still don't know why the empty parent GameObject trick don't work!?